# How to integrate SUMO into Flow?

Tags: sumo, flow-project

Repost from Antonio D.:

I just installed FLOW following all the instructions given in the following link. After executing the sugiyama example, SUMO shows an error saying this: "Error: tcpip::Storage::readIsSafe: want to read 8 bytes from Storage, but only 4 remaining". I know that after the release of SUMO 1.0.0 TraCI libraries and SUMO are no more compatible but I am not able to downgrade the last version of SUMO in my machine (MacBook). Which is the version I should downgrade tool and how can I do it?

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Repost from Flow team:

This is probably happening because your conda environment cannot find the associate binaries. I would recommend installing the binaries into your conda environment; that should fix this. You can do so from your terminal by running the following commands:

```
cd /path/to/flow
source activate flow
scripts/setup_sumo_osx.sh
```

Hope this helps.